# MySQL Slave SQL Running State - "Waiting for dependent transaction to commit" confusion

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to debug a replication lag issue.

We have a job that we run over the weekend, where we delete a large number of rows (potentially millions) from a table, currently in batches of 100. While this is running, we find that the replica can fall quite far behind our master database.

The query for the deletes is a simple `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (...)` - we use GUID's for the IDs in this table.

We have `slave_parallel_workers` set to 2 and `slave_parallel_type` set to `LOGICAL_CLOCK`, however `binlog_group_commit_sync_delay` is currently set to 0.

Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to see what is happening on the replica, it seems that only one of the workers is actually doing anything -

I can see that one worker is processing a DELETE query, and has the state `updating`, the other worker is doing nothing, with the state `Waiting for an event from Coordinator`.

Meanwhile, the Coordinator thread has the status `Waiting for dependent transaction to commit`. I'm a little confused as to what this means, and I can't see this status in the list of thread states in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slave-sql-thread-states.html).

Does the "dependent transaction" mean the Delete transaction currently running on the other worker thread on the replica (does this mean the Delete statement is locking the table)?

Or does the "dependent transaction" refer to something occurring on the Master that the replica is waiting for?

It's probably worth noting that while these Delete queries are being run, the replica is still processing a large number of Select queries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same issue, not sure if anyone has an answer?